How do I use the QuickFilter property in MUI DataGrid while using a custom toolbar?
In the documentation for MUI Data Grid, it introduces a quick filter property that you can simply use by including these properties in your DataGrid component:
slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
slotProps={{ toolbar: { showQuickFilter: true } }}

However, I am trying to pass in a custom toolbar instead of the default GridToolbar. There is more documentation on how to create the custom toolbar, but nothing written about how to still maintain the quickFilter functionality.
How can I get my desired behaviour?
If I create the custom toolbar like this as an example:
slots={{
    toolbar: () => (
        <GridToolbarContainer>
            <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
            <GridToolbarFilterButton />
            <GridToolbarDensitySelector/>
            <GridToolbarExport/>
        </GridToolbarContainer>
    )
}}

while still passing in the same slotProps of:
slotProps={{
    toolbar: {
        showQuickFilter: true,
    },
}}

The search bar does NOT appear in my toolbar.

You need to add <GridToolbarQuickFilter /> component manually to somewhere appropriate in your custom toolbar like this:
slots={{
  toolbar: () => (
     <GridToolbarContainer>
      <GridToolbarColumnsButton />
      <GridToolbarFilterButton />
      <GridToolbarDensitySelector />
      <GridToolbarExport />
      <GridToolbarQuickFilter />
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  ),
}}

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.
From the documentation:

Quick filter allows filtering rows by multiple columns with a single text input. To enable it, you can add the <GridToolbarQuickFilter /> component to your custom toolbar or pass showQuickFilter to the default <GridToolbar />.

